# Pausar Grabación con Pyaudio

Tags: python, audio

Hola a todos bueno estoy en un proyecto de desarrollar usando la librería de PyAudio, ademas usando la cámara web para capturar vídeo, en el momento e logrado que grabe el vídeo y el audio en dos archivos separados, pero se me presenta el problema cuando el usuario le da pausa a la grabación y luego retoma el proceso, el vídeo se almacena sin ningún problema pero el audio solo se graba hasta dar la señal de pausa.

Mientras el usuario no puse el vídeo tanto el archivo de audio como de vídeo coinciden, mi problema es como pausar la grabación de audio y luego retomarla espero alguien me pueda ayudar adjunto el código de mi trabajo

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gtk
import keyboard

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

flagrecord=True
chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100


def show_webcam(flagrecord):

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cam.get(4))
    FONT = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"
    filenamea = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") 

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                    channels = CHANNELS,
                    rate = RATE,
                    input = True,
                    frames_per_buffer = chunk)
    all = []

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 30, (frame_width,frame_height))

    while True:

        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        title = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d*%H:%M:%S")

        if flagrecord: 

            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "REC", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (0,0,255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (0,0,255), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (30,430),(600,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, title, (40,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            out.write(img)

            stream.start_stream()
            data = stream.read(chunk)
            all.append(data)

        else:

            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "PAUSE", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (50,430),(570,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, "Audiencias En Pausa", (60,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            stream.stop_stream()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
            break  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            flagrecord=False
        if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
            flagrecord=True 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break     

    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    data = ''.join(all)
    wf = wave.open(filenamea, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(data)
    wf.close()


def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola a todos logre pausar el audio y continuar junto con el video tengo una un retraso de 2 segundos pero creo que es cuestion de mejorar los frames anexo el codigo de la solución

Código Completo

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gtk
import keyboard

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

flagrecord=True
#chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
ropen=True
chunk = int(RATE/20) 


def show_webcam(flagrecord):

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cam.get(4))
    FONT = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"
    filenamea = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") 


    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                    channels = CHANNELS,
                    rate = RATE,
                    input = True,
                    frames_per_buffer = chunk)

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 20, (frame_width,frame_height))

    all = []
    aux = []
    stream.start_stream()

    flagaudio=False

    while True:

        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        title = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d*%H:%M:%S")

        if flagrecord: 

            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "REC", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (0,0,255), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (0,0,255), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (30,430),(600,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, title, (40,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            data = stream.read(chunk)
            aux.append(data)
            out.write(img)

        else:

            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "PAUSE", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (50,430),(570,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, "Audiencias En Pausa", (60,470), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)

            if flagaudio:
               all+=aux
               del  aux[:]
               data= 0
               stream.stop_stream()
            else:
               pass


        q=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if q == 27:
            break  
        if q == ord('p'):
            flagrecord=False
            flagaudio = True
        if q == ord('c'):
            flagrecord=True
            flagaudio=False
            stream.start_stream()
        if q == ord('q'):
            break  

    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    all+=aux
    data = ''.join(all)
    wf = wave.open(filenamea, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(data)
    wf.close()




def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Primer paso

```
flagrecord=True
#chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
ropen=True
chunk = int(RATE/20)
```

La variable chunk tiene que dividirse RATE/20 donde 20 es el numero de frames, ya que vamos a grabar de forma continua y no hay limite para el tiempo

Esta solución la encontré dentro de este post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653745/continuesly-streaming-audio-signal-real-time-infinitely-python

Segundo Paso

```
all = []
aux = []
stream.start_stream()
flagaudio=False
```

creamos a lita aux iniciamos stream.start_stream() y creamos la variable flagaudio=False que inicia en falso para que no entre dentro del primero ciclo

Tercer Paso

```
        if flagrecord: 

            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "REC", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (0,0,255), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (0,0,255), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (30,430),(600,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, title, (40,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            data = stream.read(chunk)
            aux.append(data)
            out.write(img)

        else:

            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "PAUSE", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (50,430),(570,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, "Audiencias En Pausa", (60,470), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)

            if flagaudio:
               all+=aux
               del  aux[:]
               data= 0
               stream.stop_stream()
            else:
               pass
```

Dentro del if flagrecord cuando se pausa el vídeo cuando va a falso se coloca la condiciono donde pregunta si la variable flagaudio es verdadera si es así la lista la lista all toma los valores de aux, se borra la lista para que en el siguiente ciclo tome los nuevos valores de audio por seguridad se dice que la variable data tome el valor de 0 y con stream.stop_stream() detenemos la grabación del audio

Cuarto paso

```
        q=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if q == 27:
            break  
        if q == ord('p'):
            flagrecord=False
            flagaudio = True
        if q == ord('c'):
            flagrecord=True
            flagaudio=False
            stream.start_stream()
        if q == ord('q'):
            break
```

Con el uso de q=cv2.waitKey(1) controlamos la orden de pausa (letra p), continuo de la grabación (letra c) de audio y video y salir (letra q), en cada orden le indicamos a las variables flag que creamos para que permitan el ingreso o no a uno de las condicionales de control

Para finalizar

```
    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    all+=aux
    data = ''.join(all)
    wf = wave.open(filenamea, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(data)
    wf.close()
```

finalizamos nuestro proceso de grabación tanto de vídeo como de audio y cerramos la cámara web.

En este momento solo se me presenta que tengo una perdida de audio de tres segundos para ser exactos pero lo principal que era pausar y continuar la grabación funciona de forma correcta, creo que mi falla ese en el control de los frame y del ciclo.

Espero mi solución se de ayuda y la explicación que e dado